# Google Calendar recurrence IF LAST DAY OF MONTH NOT A WORKING DAY THEN FIRST WORKING DAY OF NEXT MONTH

Tags: google-calendar-recurring-events

Is it possible to create an event (lets call it TEST) that will recur on the last day of the month but if the last day is NOT a working day (if it is a Saturday or Sunday) then it will recur on the first working day of the next month?

For example TEST will have to recur on 31/01/2020 but then will have to recur on 02/03/2020 and again on 31/03/2020. I know how to find the last day of the month FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;BYSETPOS=-1, I also know how to find the last working day of the month FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1. I tried this rule FREQ=MONTHLY;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1,1 but what it did is recur on both the last and the first working day of each month.